# Proof that $\|S_N\|_p < \infty $ is equivalent to $\|S_N f - f\|_p \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$

Tags: fourier-series, lp-spaces, harmonic-analysis, proof-explanation

I am having difficulties with the proof of proposition 1.9 in the book "Classical and multilinear harmonic analysis, Vol. 1" by C. Muscalu and W. Schlag.

> The following statements are equivalent for any $1 \leq p \leq \infty$:
>
> $(i)$ for every $f \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ (or $f \in C(\mathbb{T})$ if $p = \infty$) one has $$ \|S_Nf - f\|_p \to 0 \text{  as } N \to \infty; $$
>   $(ii)$ $\sup_N \|S_N\|_{p \to p} < \infty.$

The proof for the fact that $(i)$ implies $(ii)$ is as follows.

> Suppose that $\sup_N \|S_N\|_{p \to p} = \infty$. For every positive integer $\ell$, one can therefore find a large integer $N_\ell$ such that 
>   $$ \|S_{N_\ell}f_\ell\|_p > 2^\ell $$ 
>   where $f_\ell$ is a trigonometric polynomial with $\|f_\ell\|_p = 1$. 
>   Now let 
>   $$ f(x) = \sum_{\ell = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{\ell^2}e(M_\ell x)f_\ell(x), $$ 
>   with integers $\{M_\ell \}$ to be specified. Notice that $\|f\|_p < \infty$. Now choose a sequence $\{M_\ell\}$ tending to infinity so rapidly that the Fourier support of 
>   $$ e(M_\ell x)f_\ell(x) $$ 
>   is to the right of the Fourier support of 
>   $$ g_\ell(x) := \sum_{j=1}^{\ell-1} \frac{1}{j^2}e(M_j x)f_j(x) $$ 
>   for every $j \geq 2$. We also demand that $M_\ell - N_\ell \to \infty$ as $\ell \to \infty$ and that $S_{M_\ell - N_\ell-1}f = g_\ell$ and $S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}f = g_{\ell+1}$. Then
>   $$ \|(S_{M_\ell+N_\ell} - S_{M_\ell-N_\ell-1})f\|_p = \frac{1}{\ell^2} \|S_{N_\ell}f_\ell\|_p > \frac{2^\ell}{\ell^2}.$$

The part I am having trouble with is the definition of the numbers $\{M_\ell\}$. I get that we can impose that they grow fast enough so that
$$ S_{M_\ell-N_\ell-1} f = g_\ell $$
since $g_\ell$ does not depend on $M_\ell$, but how is it that we can have 
$$ S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}f = g_{\ell+1} $$
when the term $e(M_\ell x)f_\ell(x)$ appears in $g_{\ell+1}$? I seems to me that the Fourier support of this term is the Fourier support of $f_\ell$ shifted to the right by a factor of $M_\ell$. Then, don't we need $f_\ell(k) = 0$ for $k > N_\ell$ so that all the terms of $g_{\ell+1}$ appear in $S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}f$?

Also, can we deduce from this that
$$ g_{\ell+1} = S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}g_{\ell+1} $$
which seems needed in order to obtain the last equality?

Comment: This implication also follows from the Banach-Steinhaus theorem: if $\sup_N \|S_N\|_p = \infty$, then there exists $f$ s.t. $\|S_N f\|_p$ is unbounded, contradiction!

Comment: Regarding the proof here, there is something apart from what you say that I don't understand: in the last line we have $|(S_{M_\ell+N_\ell} - S_{M_\ell-N_\ell-1})f|=|g_{\ell+1}-g_\ell |= \frac1{\ell^2} |f_\ell|$. I don't see where they get $S_{N_\ell} f_\ell$??

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem I have, though it can be avoided if we know $g_{\ell+1} = S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}g_{\ell+1}$ by adding and subtracting in order to obtain $S_{M_\ell+N_\ell}(g_{\ell+1} - g_\ell)$ . As for the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, the book states that it can indeed be used to get the result but the proof here is an alternative way.

Comment: But that equality implies $f_\ell=S_{N_\ell} f_\ell$ which is impossible by choice of $f_\ell$.

Comment: I didn't think of that. The last inequality of the proof only implies the equality of the norms though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us forget about what they write after the definition of $g_\ell$. I will try to reconstruct what is meant.

Let $M'_\ell$ denote the size of the Fourier support of $f_\ell$. So, $\widehat{f_\ell}(k)=0$ if $|k|>M'_\ell$. 
We have $M'_\ell>N_\ell$ by choice of $f_\ell$.

We want $M_\ell$ to be chosen large enough so that the intervals $[M_\ell - M'_\ell, M_\ell + M'_\ell]$ (the Fourier support of $e(M_\ell x)f_\ell(x)$) are disjoint.

The idea is now to recover $S_{N_\ell} f_\ell$ by an appropriate clipping in frequency. The operator $S_{A}-S_{B-1}$ (where $A\ge B$) cuts out the frequency annulus $[-A,-B]\cup [B,A]$. So we have that

$$(S_{M_\ell+N_\ell} - S_{M_\ell-N_\ell-1})f$$

selects precisely the components of $f$ with frequency in the interval $[M_\ell-N_\ell, M_\ell + N_\ell]\subset [M_\ell-M'_\ell, M_\ell+M'_\ell]$, so it equals 
$$1/\ell^2 e(M_\ell x) S_{N_\ell} f_\ell.$$

Now we proved the last line in the proof you quoted. So in the book one should just drop the definition of $g_\ell$ and these two identities regarding $g_\ell$ entirely. We don't need them and they are flawed as we discussed above in the comments.

From here it is easy to finish the proof. Suppose $M_\ell$ is large enough such that $M_\ell - N_\ell\to\infty$ as $\ell\to\infty$. Then $(S_{M_\ell+N_\ell} - S_{M_\ell-N_\ell-1})f$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\ell$ by assumption. So we arrive at a contradiction as $\ell\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, this is much clearer.